# Join based on condition?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to condition a `join` based on a condition?

For example, if `@DoJoin` is *true* then do the `inner join`. It would replace something like this:

```
declare @DoJoin bit = 1

if @DoJoin = 1
BEGIN 
    select T.* from T inner join L on T.col = L.col
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    select T.* from T
END
```

Comment: What do you want to do if @doJoin is 0? A left join?

Comment: In this case it would be an `inner join`, like in the example.

Comment: The best you could do is extend the JOIN condition through a WHERE clause. Here is one way: `...LEFT join L on T.col = L.col WHERE @DoJoin =0 OR L.col is not null`

Comment: Laughing Vergil's comment is the only correct answer so far, but frankly, if you care about performance, you're better of with the `IF..` construct that you already have.  It will make for the simplest execution plan and perform better than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding how your data might work, you probably don't need a join at all, because your just using the join as a filter. So if that's the case, you can just do this, and just have one query.

```
select T.* from T 
where @DoJoin = 0 or exists(SELECT * FROM L where L.col = T.col)
```

Comment: Thanks. Replaced`inner join` with `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DoJoin BIT = 1

SELECT
    T.*
FROM 
    T LEFT JOIN L ON T.col = L.col
WHERE
    --Optional INNER/LEFT JOIN  
    (
        --LEFT JOIN 
        @DoJoin = 0
        OR
        --INNER JOIN
        (
            -- only return rows from T where they have a record in L
            @DoJoin = 1 
            AND 
            L.col IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
```

Comment: This is not what I interpret the question as asking.   I believe that if `@DoJoin = 0` then no JOIN should be performed at all, as opposed to changing the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Laughing Vergils comment above reads better, but does the same thing. 
To truly not do a join the only option is to use the IF statement as in the question.